# question.migrated.to_site null

Tags: bug, status-norepro

http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/questions/322108?sort=activity&order=desc

```
{
  "total": 1,
  "page": 1,
  "pagesize": 30,
  "questions": [
    {
      "tags": [
        "discussion",
        "fun"
      ],
      "answer_count": 0,
      "favorite_count": 7,
      "closed_date": 1251308956,
      "closed_reason": "belongs on meta",
      "migrated": {
        "new_question_id": 17817,
        "on_date": 1251308956
      },
      "question_timeline_url": "/questions/322108/timeline",
      "question_comments_url": "/questions/322108/comments",
      "question_answers_url": "/questions/322108/answers",
      "question_id": 322108,
      "locked_date": 1251308959,
      "owner": {
        "user_id": 23234,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "display_name": "Jeff Yates",
        "reputation": 16689,
        "email_hash": "3b0d930715cf8f5729e177981f69f44e"
      },
      "creation_date": 1227732863,
      "last_edit_date": 1251308945,
      "last_activity_date": 1251308945,
      "up_vote_count": 21,
      "down_vote_count": 10,
      "view_count": 1041,
      "score": 11,
      "community_owned": true,
      "title": "Are Shakespeare's monkeys here?"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This was probably related to `/sites` acting up yesterday, can't reproduce today.